# executing shell script in php and assigning the value to the html slider

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having one html code, php code and one shell script. In html I am having one slider with min value set to 0 and max value set to 100. when I run my php script it will returns a value by reading a file and I want that value to be assigned to the slider value in html page. Shell script is perfectly working and returning value.

```
##PHP Code
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/Propertyhandler getConfiguration lenght');
echo "$output";
?>
```

```
<form id="myForm">
  Number<br>
  <input type="range" name="NumRange" min="0" max="100" value="30" oninput="this.form.NumInput.value=this.value" />
  <span class='number-wrapper'>
    <input type="number" name="NumInput" min="0" max="100" value="30" oninput="this.form.NumRange.value=this.value" />
    </span><br>
</form>
```

Comment: So, what's your issue? You've posted code that executes a shell script so what happens when you run it? We can only help if we know what you want us to help you with. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In my html page the php code is not getting executed but it just prints the php code in the browser. If I run manually like "php sample.php" then it is getting executed successfully.

Comment: How are you opening the page? Through a local web server or by double clicking on the file? Does the HTML-file have the file extension `.html` or `.php`? For PHP to be parsed on web page, you need to go through a web server and the file extension should be `.php` so the web server knows that it should parse it as PHP. Unless you've actively configured it to regard `.html` as PHP files, that is.